# Unable to triger change() in Mac safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, selenium

`$("input[data-test='title']").val('text').change();` is not working in MAC safari, but working absolutely fine in Chrome and Firefox.

Value gets entered in input field for a moment and vanish immediately. I also tried `$("input[data-test='title']").val('text').triger('change');`

I have also tried `sendkeys()` function, that is also not working for MAC Safari.

Could some one please let me know any alternative for this

Comment: `triger('change')` should be `trigger('change')`

Comment: Any error with `sendkeys()` ?

Comment: `$("input[data-test='title']").val('text').change()`  should work in all browsers  - do you have an `...on("change",function() { form.submit() })` or similar?

Comment: 'An element command could not be completed because element is not visible on page' error is thrown when i am using sendkeys(). I have put enough wait also but that also didn't work. Regarding ...on("change"),function(){form.submit()}) i am not sure if it is available as i am working as QA and i don't have access to developer's code .  Could you please suggest any other alternative for this?